# Eclipse nothing to build message in C project

Tags: c, eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse Mars although I have been doing most of my work on Android Studio. The reason is I need another tool, which is not compatible with Android Studio. The procedures I followed instructed to create an executable C project. I then added hello world to it, but I can an error stating there is nothing to build. What am I doing wrong? All of this is setup on Ubuntu Virtual Machine. I have reviewed the posts online, but the error seems to be specific to each case. Here is a screen capture...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiler is simply telling you that your code was already compiled and there are no changes in your code, then it does not compile.
Is a builtin feature of compilers, if there are no changes in source code file, compilers do not waste time.

`Clean Project` before to `Build Project` or modify Hello.c and Build your project.